# Error in http connection in android

Tags: android, json, http

Im getting this error. I don't know what is wrong. Can someone help me with it? Searched a bit, But dont know how to solve it... It is kinda urgent.

This is my code:

```
   package nearest.moskee.almawada;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class MoskeeJSON extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    String url;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    InputStream is = null;

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MoskeeJSON.this,
                    "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                //HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("url", url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    public JSONArray getCloseMosquesInJSON(float lat, float lng, float radius) {

        String result = "";

        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            url = "http://www.moskee.org/finder/getCloseDataInJSON.php?lat="
                    + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&radius=" + radius;
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
            Log.v("URL =>", url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("result", result);
            Log.e("resultLength", result.length() + "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // parse json data
        if (result.length() == 5) {
            Log.i("result is ", "LEEG");
            return null;
        } else {
            JSONArray jArray = null;
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parrsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            return jArray;
        }
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

}
```

The Errors

> 06-07 15:04:07.329: I/dalvikvm(1643): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   06-07 15:04:07.370: I/dalvikvm(1643): Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' 06-07 15:04:07.828: I/dalvikvm(1643):
>   threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 06-07 15:04:07.898: I/dalvikvm(1643):
>   Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' 06-07 15:04:07.988:
>   D/gralloc_goldfish(1643): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   06-07 15:04:24.098: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1643): KeyEvent:
>   ACTION_UP but key was not down. 06-07 15:04:24.098:
>   D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1643):   in
>   android.widget.EditText@412aa7f0 06-07 15:04:24.098:
>   D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1643):   0: sent at 16907476000000,
>   KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15,
>   metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=16907476,
>   downTime=16907424, deviceId=0, source=0x301 } 06-07 15:04:24.098:
>   D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1643):   -- recent events -- 06-07
>   15:04:24.098: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1643):   1: sent at
>   16902546208000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=229.0,
>   y[0]=2.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0,
>   flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0,
>   eventTime=16902546, downTime=16902470, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
>   06-07 15:04:24.098: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1643):   2: sent
>   at 16902470916000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0,
>   x[0]=229.0, y[0]=2.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0,
>   metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0,
>   eventTime=16902470, downTime=16902470, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
>   06-07 15:04:27.649: V/Adres =>(1643): Pierenbergstraat, Antwerpen
>   06-07 15:04:27.649: V/IL GeoPoint latitude =>(1643): 51.18809127807617
>   06-07 15:04:27.669: V/IL GeoPoint longitude =>(1643):
>   4.380319118499756 06-07 15:04:27.679: E/GA(1643): GA 06-07 15:04:28.219: I/dalvikvm(1643): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 06-07
>   15:04:28.339: I/dalvikvm(1643): Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' 06-07 15:04:28.419: D/dalvikvm(1643):
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 192K, 3% free 9323K/9607K, paused 7ms+6ms 06-07
>   15:04:28.419: W/CursorWrapperInner(1643): Cursor finalized without
>   prior close() 06-07 15:04:28.419: W/CursorWrapperInner(1643): Cursor
>   finalized without prior close() 06-07 15:04:28.719: I/dalvikvm(1643):
>   threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 06-07 15:04:28.719: D/dalvikvm(1643):
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 3% free 9653K/9927K, paused 54ms 06-07
>   15:04:28.829: I/dalvikvm(1643): Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' 06-07 15:04:28.909: E/log_tag(1643): Error in
>   http connection java.lang.NullPointerException 06-07 15:04:28.909:
>   E/log_tag(1643): Error converting result
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 06-07 15:04:28.909: E/log_tag(1643):
>   Error parrsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character
>   0 of  06-07 15:04:29.110: I/Center map?(1643): 51188091,4380319 06-07
>   15:04:29.110: I/Center map?(1643): Toegepast zonder erreurs 06-07
>   15:04:29.259: I/dalvikvm(1643): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 06-07
>   15:04:29.370: I/dalvikvm(1643): Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' 06-07 15:04:29.649: I/MapActivity(1643):
>   Handling network change notification:CONNECTED 06-07 15:04:29.649:
>   E/MapActivity(1643): Couldn't get connection factory client 06-07
>   15:04:29.810: I/dalvikvm(1643): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 06-07
>   15:04:29.910: I/dalvikvm(1643): Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' 06-07 15:04:30.089: D/dalvikvm(1643):
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 3% free 9946K/10183K, paused 59ms 06-07
>   15:04:30.229: I/dalvikvm(1643): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3 06-07
>   15:04:30.389: I/dalvikvm(1643): Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' 06-07 15:04:31.499: D/dalvikvm(1643):
>   GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 2% free 10360K/10567K, paused 8ms+7ms

MoskeeResult

```
     package nearest.moskee.almawada;

import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MoskeeResults extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMap);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.iconmoskee);
        OverlayItems itemizedoverlay = new OverlayItems(drawable,this);

        try {
            MoskeeJSON m = new MoskeeJSON();

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            float lat = 0;
            float lng = 0;
            float radius = 1;
            lat = (float) extras.getDouble("lat");
            lng = (float) extras.getDouble("lng");


            JSONArray arrMosques = m.getCloseMosquesInJSON(lat, lng, radius);


            if (arrMosques != null) {
                Log.i("Array aangemaakt", "Array is aangemaakt, het bevat "
                        + arrMosques.length() + " moskeëen");
                for (int i = 0; i < arrMosques.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row;
                    row = arrMosques.getJSONObject(i);
                    double jlat = row.getDouble("Latitude");
                    double jlng = row.getDouble("Longitude");
                    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(
                            (int) (jlat * 1e6), (int) (jlng * 1e6)),
                            row.getString("Naam"), row.getString("Straat"));
                    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                    Log.i("=>", "Another mosque is added to the map");

                }
                Log.i("Array aangemaakt", "Array is aangemaakt, het bevat "
                        + arrMosques.length() + " moskeëen");
                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Aantal gevonden moskeëen")
                        .setMessage(
                                "Er zijn " + arrMosques.length()
                                        + " moskeëen gevonden in deze straal")
                        .create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Aantal gevonden moskeëen")
                        .setMessage(
                                "Er zijn geen moskeëen gevonden in deze straal.\nProbeer opnieuw te zoeken met een groter bereik")
                        .create();
                alert.show();
            }


            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

            mc = mapView.getController();

            GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1e6), (int) (lng * 1e6));
            Log.i("Center map?", "" + (int) (lat * 1e6) + ","
                    + (int) (lng * 1e6));
            mc.setCenter(center);
            Log.i("Center map?", "Toegepast zonder erreurs");
            mc.setZoom(17);

        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("JASOEN EXCEPTIOEN",
                    "I have absolutely no idea what's going on..."
                            + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is in line 87 in your MoskeeResults.java?

Comment: Line 86-87: Log.i("Array aangemaakt", "Array is aangemaakt, het bevat "
     + arrMosques.length() + " moskeëen");

Comment: This code is not contained in the code you pasted here. Anyway the variable `arrMosques` is null.

Comment: How can it be null? I have checked the php file and i get everything back

Comment: because `getCloseMosquesInJSON` might return null in some cases!

Comment: Are you refering to this snippet?

Comment: if (result.length() == 5)
//...

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out the error is in the line where you log.

```
JSONArray arrMosques = m.getCloseMosquesInJSON(lat, lng, radius);
Log.i("Array aangemaakt", "Array is aangemaakt, het bevat " + arrMosques.length() + " moskeëen");
```

As you call `m.getCloseMosquesInJson()` right before, this method might return null in the following code block:

```
if (result.length() == 5) {
    Log.i("result is ", "LEEG");
    return null; // HERE
} else {
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parrsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jArray; // HERE! might be null when JSONException was thrown
}
```

You should check for `null` before logging the length of the array!

Comment: Oke ill check it out now and try to solve it. Ill let you know how it went!!

Comment: Just beneath it, i have: 
if (arrMosques != null)
//...

else
...

I did like you said: Ive logged AFTER the else. But i keep getting the same expection. 
Did i do something wrong?

Comment: You can't log `arrMosques` if it is null and checking for `null` AFTER you tried to log it fails with a NullPointerException. So just do the Log AFTER you checked for null.

Comment: if (arrMosques != null) {
...
}
else{
...
}

Comment: then 

Log.i("Array aangemaakt", "Array is aangemaakt, het bevat "
     + arrMosques.length() + " moskeëen");

Comment: Have you moved the Log command into the if clause? And please stop spamming comments. Use the 600 characters or better update the question with your current code!

Comment: I have updated the message. Yes I have put the log in the if clause. Still getting errors.. Sorry for the spam, it is when i press the 'enter' button that it happens.

Comment: Any idea where it error must be coming from?? I've been looking whole night yesterday and now the whole day but no progress...

Comment: Without the error I have no idea... please update your question with the new error and stack trace

Comment: `Error in http connection java.lang.NullPointerException` means somewhere in your `doInBackground()` you have a null value. Use the debugger to find out which variable is null there. And I just realize that you use the AsyncTask in a wrong way! You can't just call `execute()` and expect to directly use your `is` variable. You should search for a tutorial about `AsyncTask` and rewrite your code. The current one is simply completely wrong. It will never work the way you expect it.

Comment: Ill take another look at it. Is it necessary to use AsyncTask?

Comment: As you use network connections yes. Otherwise you get a NetworkOnUiThreadException.